# Prevent changes of instances of an object based on the value of a property

Tags: c#, exception, generics, properties

I have an object like this:

(i have the private fields too but remove them for simplify the example)

```
public MyObject
{
  public int prop1 {get(); set()}
  public string prop2 {get(); set()}
  public bool prop3 {get(); set()}

  public bool enabled {get(); private set();}

  public void enable()
  {
    this.enabled = true;
  }


  public void disable()
  {
    this.enabled = false;
  }
}
```

My object is the result of an audit analysis, when it's send to client must not be edited anymore so i want to prevent changes on prop1-2-3 when the 'enabled' property is false so i add this method:

```
private T setProperty<T>(T value)
{
  if (this.enabled == true)
  {
     return value:
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

and edit property in this way:

```
 public int prop1
    {
        get{};
        set
        {
            // see how we can call a method below? or any code for that matter..
            prop1 = setProperty<int>(value);
        }
    }
```

is a good solution or are there better ways?
what type of Exception may i return in the 'set' method?

Comment: What is the context of your task? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach but watch for StackoverFlow! When are the properties set in general? This may enable a different approach, but with the information you have givcen this seems okay...

Comment: Instead of `prop1 = setProperty<int>(value);` you should use `_prop1 = setProperty<int>(value);`, that is the private variable, not the property. You'll get stuck in a loop otherwise.

Comment: My object is the result of an audit analysis, when it's send to client must not be edited anymore (i edited my question to add this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, your property is recursive and will explode - either with a stack-overflow, or an infinite loop if the JIT decides to tail-call it.

Other than that, the *approach* would certainly work. Personally I'd use `InvalidOperationException`, perhaps with a message that mentions the `enabled` flag. Also, for convenience I'd probably do:

```
private int prop1;
public int Prop1 {
    get { return prop1; }
    set { SetValue(ref prop1, value); }
}
private string prop2;
public string Prop2 {
    get { return prop2; }
    set { SetValue(ref prop2, value); }
}
private bool prop3;
public bool Prop3 {
    get { return prop3; }
    set { SetValue(ref prop3, value); }
}
void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value) {
    if(!Enabled) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
          "The property cannot be changed because the Enabled flag is not set");
    }
    field = value;
}
public bool Enabled {get;private set;}
```

Comment: as I said in the note i have the private fileds but not write here, did't think of the loop, sorry :( Why you pass also the ref to filed to the method and set it there? there are advantages?

Comment: @gt.guybrush much of a muchness, really; that works for me, and plays nicely if you later want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` by checking whether the old value matches the new value, etc. If you don't want to do that; meh, you could also just call `ThrowIfFrozen(); prop2 = value;` etc

Comment: I hope to implement INotifyPropertyChanged  with fody or MindOfmagic. But like the idea of assignement do in one place, marked as solution ;)